# How to alert user about refresh in angular

Tags: angular7

[image: alert]
HI I want to catch the window refresh event and alert the user with a meassage but if user choses to refresh I want to redidrect to a specific URL . Note I'm using Angular7.

```
@HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"]) unloadHandler(event: Event) {
    console.log("Processing beforeunload...");
    // Do more processing...
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Well I've manage to raise an alert but 
1.I want to customize the message in dialog box
2.when the user still clicks on reload button I want to route it on click.
But the alert is default and I don't know a way around to customize.
Would appreciate some help

Answer (score 4):

can you please try this.

**JavaScript**

```
window.BeforeUnloadEvent = (ev) => {
    let result = confirm("Changes you made may not be saved.");
    if (result) {
        alert("process");
    } else {
        alert("stay on page");
    }
}
```

**edit:: TypeScript**

**note: this code only works when we refresh with f5.**

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.css']
})

export class DemoComponent {

  constructor() {
  }

  @HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"]) unloadHandler(event: Event) {
    let result = confirm("Changes you made may not be saved.");
    if (result) {
      // Do more processing...
    }
    event.returnValue = false; // stay on same page
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is pure javascript but I'm not sure it will work in typescript?in@Angular to be more precise

Comment: Yes, this is pure JavaScript and it's not work with TypeScript. We need to import HostListener from @angular/core. and modify code as you define in question. here i am edit my answer which work  when we refresh with "f5".

Comment: Thanks @sachinsuthariya .But I've already used Host listener and f5 does not address my issue because the user will never use f5 to refresh he'll use the browser  refresh ideally

Answer (score 2):

can u try this.
add code in your component

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
unloadHandler(event: Event) {
  window.opener.location.reload();
}
```